# Flexbox containers not stretching height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a codepen that I am working on that has 3 boxes that I am using flexbox with. The issue I am coming into is that one of the boxes does not have a footer so it does not have the same height as the other 2 boxes. Is there a way to have the 3 boxes stretch to the same height even if there is no footer?

```
<article class="box-orange">
  <header>
    <h1 class="subject">Total Viewing Time</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <h2 class="count-large">30.45</h2>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="left">
      <h1 class="title">Internal</h2>
      <span class="count">
        100
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1 class="title">Public</h1>
      <span class="count">
      245
      </span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/pertrai1/pen/RRZOOK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three sections/boxes *are* the same height, it's just that none of them have a background color applied.

I'd suggest you apply your default colors to the boxes and **override** that bg color for specific sections.

```
.box-green {
  background: #9fcf91;
  /* added this */
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XKybJv)